# Using Asterisks in Python parser of ArcGIS Label Expression Builder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser, expression

I am trying to create a label expression that labels features that contain hike in their name (versus those that don't).

I have tried something like this:

```
def FindLabel ([Name]):
    if [Name] is "*hike*":
        return [Name]
```

But that eliminates all of my labels, instead of just labeling the hikes with hike in their name.

How would I do this in the label expression builder?

Answer (score 7):

Please follow the python syntax-Just check if `hike` is in the `Name`. Below should work

```
def FindLabel ([Name]):
    if 'hike' in [Name]:
        return [Name]
```

But if you need to label only `Name` does not contain `hike` use below-

```
def FindLabel ([Name]):
    if 'hike' not in [Name]:
        return [Name]
```

`'LIKE'` is an SQL operator that may be used with wildcards e.g. asterisk, percent sign etc but here you need to use pure python!

For more on arcmap label expression please consult arcmap documentation e.g.[here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/about-building-label-expressions.htm).

**Edit:**

---

If you want to use SQL and avoid python expression then  use **Maplex Label Manger** ,**most efficient labeling system for arcmap sofar**, as below-

[image: demo]

If you want more label class and each class with different properties (SQL query and label style) then you can and class as you want as below-
[image: class]
For more on SQL expression use ESRI documentation e.g.[here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm).
Or use the answer provided by @Midavalo if want to use classic labeling.

Comment: I tried the Pythonic method you posted and that still did not work (it eliminated all the labels rather than just the ones I wanted). I ended up just creating SQL statements to filter them out. Thank you!!

Comment: @user48149 Ah! first code label all that have `hike` in them and second does the reverse! Any way, i am happy that you managed to get things done.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to using code in the label parser, you can filter labels and have different label styles for different labels, by using Label Classes instead of changing the label parser:

1. In your layer properties Label Tab, select "Define classes of features and label each class differently" from the Method drop-down.

   [image]
2. Click on the "Add" button to add a new label class and enter a name for your class (in this case "Hike")

   [image]
3. Set a SQL query to filter to the values you want to label

   [image]
4. And OK out to view your labels

   [image]

This method allows you to create completely different labels for different values (and different fields if desired).  Each class can be set up with different styles, fonts, colours, scales, placement settings etc.